# VB.Net Equivalent in C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I am Validating a TextBox on it's KeyPress Event in VB.

VB.Net

```
If InStr("0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`~!@#$%^&*()_+|\[]{};:<>/?,.'" & """" & Chr(8), Chr(KeyAscii)) = 0 Then KeyAscii = 0
```

What will be it's equivalent in C# ?
Thanks.

Comment: type "vb.net to c# convertor" into google...

Comment: Here you GO! [Developer Fusion](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/) or [CodeTranslator](http://www.carlosag.net/tools/codetranslator/)

Comment: try it and you will see http://bit.ly/JJWpR9

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From [DeveloperFusion](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/) :

```
if (Strings.InStr("0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`~!@#$%^&*()_+|\\[]{};:<>/?,.'" + "\"" + Strings.Chr(8), Strings.Chr(KeyAscii)) == 0)
KeyAscii = 0;
```

From [CodeTranslator](http://www.carlosag.net/tools/codetranslator/) :

```
if (((("0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`~!@#$%^&*()_+|\\[]{};:<>/?,.\'" + ("\"" + '\8')).IndexOf(((char)(KeyAscii))) + 1) 
        == 0))
{
KeyAscii = 0;
}
```

[I dont know which one is correct! Probablity : 1st one]

Comment: @Downvoter Care to Comment whats wrong??

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Strings.InStr("0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`~!@#$%^&*()_+|\\[]{};:<>/?,.'" + "\"" + Strings.Chr(8), Strings.Chr(KeyAscii)) == 0)
KeyAscii = 0;
```

courtesy [Telerik converter](http://converter.telerik.com/)

You will need to reference Microsoft.VisualBasic library which has implementation of [String.InStr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.instr.aspx) method.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Strings.InStr("0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`~!@#$%^&*()_+|\\[]{};:<>/?,.'" + "\"" + Strings.Chr(8), Strings.Chr(KeyAscii)) == 0)
    KeyAscii = 0;
```

I am used this [Converter](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/)